# making a phon call from browser on phone

Tags: javascript, system-calls, twilio-api, phone-call

hello Guys i Try to do a phone call Frome browser on mobile ,So i code This line of code in a Button With an click évent listener,

```
window.open(`tel:\*${numberPhone.value}#`, "_self"`)
```

the result is initiating a phone call , then i have to press the button call on my phone to do so.
i dont know how to do that

the probleme is, i want the call to pass automatically when i press the button on my browser . how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as the browser cannot control the native phone app. The user will always need to opt in to actually make the call.